# how to get variables from AngularJS and use them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am creating a photo-editing app with Ionic & Cordova. I read online that it is possible to get AngularJS variables and use them in JS. But I tried it and I am getting an error in console:
app.js:1271 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scope is not a function

Here is my code:

```
//Loading the variable from AngularJS
        window.onload = function() {
            var sources = {

                yoda: $('[ng-controller="SecureController"]').scope().pictureUrl
            };
            loadImages(sources, initStage);

        };


 //Using ngCordova to capture the image and set the image link to $scope.pictureUrl. *This part works*

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
        .then(function(imageData) {
            syncArray.$add({image: imageData});
            $scope.pictureUrl= 'data:image/jpeg:base64,' + data
            .then(function() {
                alert("Image has been uploaded");
            });
```

Comment: Could you show more code? Is this in a controller or perhaps a service? It may just be that you have not defined $scope as a dependency.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if your jQuery resource reference is after your angualrjs resource reference, angular switches to angular jqlite, and thus the jQuery selector does not know about `.scope()`

I have created the following three jsfiddles to demonstrate, example 3 will have the error in the console:

[Example1](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/g74ze2L6/2/): No Jquery - If no jquery is referenced you have to use the angular jqlite

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-controller="SecureController">
  <h1>{{pictureUrl}}</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('SecureController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pictureUrl = 'this is a test url';
}]);

window.onload = function() {
  var sources = {
    yoda: angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv')).scope().pictureUrl
  };
  console.log(sources.yoda);
  alert(sources.yoda);
}
```

[Example2](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/g74ze2L6/3/): jQuery is included before angular - Use the jQuery selector

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" ng-controller="SecureController">
  <h1>{{pictureUrl}}</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('SecureController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pictureUrl = 'this is a test url';
}]);

window.onload = function() {  
  var sources = {
    yoda: $('#myDiv').scope().pictureUrl
  };
  console.log(sources.yoda);
  alert(sources.yoda);
}
```

[Example3](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/g74ze2L6/4/): jQuery is included after angaular - You will get the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scope is not a function` error

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" ng-controller="SecureController">
  <h1>{{pictureUrl}}</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('SecureController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pictureUrl = 'this is a test url';
}]);

window.onload = function() {  
  var sources = {
    yoda: $('#myDiv').scope().pictureUrl
  };
  console.log(sources.yoda);
  alert(sources.yoda);
}
```

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answer, but I will check my script. As I said, I am coding with the Ionic Framework soall the references are made in the index page. Anyway, I will definitely check to see and get back to you accordingly